# Create subindices based on two categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing two categorical variables. I would like to add a third column with ascending indices for each of the categories, where one category is nested within the other.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

foo = ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b']
bar = [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':foo,'bar':bar})
```

which gives you:

```
  foo  bar
0   a    0
1   a    0
2   a    1
3   a    1
4   b    0
5   b    0
6   b    1
7   b    1
```

Add a third column to `df` so that you get:

```
  foo  bar  foobar
0   a    0       0
1   a    0       1
2   a    1       0
3   a    1       1
4   b    0       2
5   b    0       3
6   b    1       2
7   b    1       3
```

I guess this can be somehow done with `groupby()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
s = df.groupby(['foo','bar']).cumcount()

df['foobar'] = df['foo'].factorize()[0] * (s.max() + 1) + s
```

Output:

```
  foo  bar  foobar
0   a    0       0
1   a    0       1
2   a    1       0
3   a    1       1
4   b    0       2
5   b    0       3
6   b    1       2
7   b    1       3
```